# Positive probability of event in coin tosses

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Lets say I toss a coin infinite times such that all tosses are independent.
Does the event "For all $n\in \mathbb N$, we had exactly $n$ heads in a row between the toss number $3^n$ and toss number $3^{n+1}$" have a positive probability?

Is it it true for $n^2$?

I am thinking about using Borel-Cantelli but don't know how to begin formalizing the problem.

Comment: Do you mean exactly $n$ heads or at least $n$ heads?

Comment: @lulu I have edited the question.

Comment: But you have not clarified it.  What does "exactly $n$ heads in a row" mean?  Just take $n=1$, say.  So we are looking between $3$ and $9$.  Which sequences are good and which are bad?

Comment: @lulu: I agree that it's unclear, but does it matter for this particular question?  We require only a positive probability.  So long as $3^{n+1}-3^n \geq n$ (or $n^2$), shouldn't the probability be greater than $0$?

Comment: @BrianTung But you need this for all $n$.  Depending on what the OP is asking, that sounds like an infinite product wherein the factors decrease to $0$.  But perhaps (probably?) I have an entirely incorrect picture of what is being asked.

Comment: @z00x: I think lulu (and I) would like clarification on the following: 1.  Does a run of three heads include any runs of exactly two heads (for example)?  2.  Do we look at tosses $3^n$ *through* $3^{n+1}$, or do we not include tosses $3^n$ and $3^{n+1}$?  3.  Do we look outside that range for the purposes of identifying runs of exact length?  For example, for the following: Suppose $n = 1$ and the first nine tosses are HHHTTTHHH.  Does that sequence satisfy the conditions because the third toss (viewed solely in the context of tosses $3$ through $9$) is a singleton heads?  Or is it not?

Comment: @lulu: One of the few things the question *is* clear about is that it is for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  We are not concerned with the *limiting* probability as $n \to \infty$.  For any finite $n$, the probability is non-zero.  (Of course, if OP decides they do want the limiting probability, then we'll need to be more definitive about the conditions.)

Answer (score 0):

The question as stated currently (2018-02-09-1820 UT) is somewhat unclear, but we will view it in the following restrictive way:

- For any $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$, we look only at the sequence of tosses $3^n+1$ *through* $3^{n+1}-1$; that is, we look at $2 \times 3^n - 1$ tosses.
- We require that the run of $n$ consecutive heads be entirely isolated *within* that sequence.

We will show, broadly, that the probability is always non-zero, and that its limiting probability, as $n \to \infty$, is $1$.

First, we note that the number of tosses we look at, $2 \times 3^n - 1$, is always greater than $n+2$, for $n \geq 1$.  It is true for $n = 1$, and whenever it is true for $n = k$, it is (almost) trivially true for $n = k+1$.  Induction thus suffices to establish our claim.

The probability that the first $n+2$ tosses in our sequence have the form $THH \cdots HHT$ is $\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}$.  This is non-zero for any $n \geq 1$; since this is a lower bound for the probability of *any* run of exactly $n$ heads, that probability must also be non-zero for any $n \geq 1$.

---

[Note: The 'align' environment doesn't seem to be working at the moment?  Formatting may be askew.]

We now show, broadly, that the limiting probability is $1$.  Not a rigorous proof, but you can proceed sort of along these lines:

It may not escape your notice that not only does $2 \times 3^n - 1 > n+2$, but the former grows rather faster than the latter.  For any $n \geq 1$, in fact, we look at, altogether,

$$
\left\lfloor \frac{2 \times 3^n - 1}{n+2} \right\rfloor
$$

segments of $n+2$ tosses.  Note that for $n \geq 1$,

$$
\left\lfloor \frac{2 \times 3^n - 1}{n+2} \right\rfloor
    \geq \frac{3^n}{n+2} \\
    \geq \frac{3^n}{3n} \\
    \geq \frac{3^n}{3(6/5)^n} \\
    \geq \frac{(5/2)^n}{3}
$$

(There probably was an easier way to get to what I wanted, but that'll work.)  Recall that a segment of length $n+2$ has the form $THH \cdots HHT$ with probability $\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}$, so the probability that *none* of $\frac{(5/2)^n}{3}$ segments have such a form is *at most*

$$
\left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{n+2}} \right)^\frac{(5/2)^n}{3}
    = \left[ \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{n+2}} \right)^{2^{n+2}} \right]
     ^\frac{(5/2)^n}{3\times 2^{n+2}} \\
    \to \exp \left( - \frac{(5/4)^n}{12} \right) \\ \to 0
$$

So the limiting probability is $1-0 = 1$ that there *will* be such a run, somewhere in those segments.